# DJANGO - template/database link-up issue for uploaded/admin files

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a site that's almost ready to be published but I have one problem that's driving me insane!

Something's wrong with the way I'm calling links to uploaded images in my template.

Basically I have a model Products with another model Images attached to Products as a foreign key. On the individual product pages when I update an image everything works as expected. But on the front page where I want to iteratively show the first image of each collection it is not updating and instead always showing the first image that was uploaded.

From what I understand it must be something to do with the way I am calling the urls and their relationship to the database.

On product pages (where it works):

```
{% for image in images %}
   <img src="{{ image.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

On front page where it doesn't:

```
{% for product in product_list %}
  <img src="{{ product.image_set.all.0.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

And here's the views for each page:

```
def index(request):
    product_list = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'product_list' : product_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/products.html', context)

def productpage(request, product_id):
    product_list = Product.objects.all()
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    images = product.image_set.all()
    return render(request, 'polls/productpage.html', {'product': product, 'images': images, 'product_list' : product_list})
```

On the product pages I can just call the Images model because it only refers to the set of images for the specific product. But on the index I can't do this as far as I know. Is there a way?

Comment: The code looks fine. What do you mean by this statement `it is not updating and instead always showing the first image that was uploaded`?? This `{{ product.image_set.all.0.image.url }}` will always shows the first image for every product in list.

Comment: That's the thing.. It's showing the first image ever uploaded. So, when I first made the product and first uploaded an image, {{ product.image_set.all.0.image.url }} always points to THAT image... but when I update that image nothing changes.

Comment: @AamirAdnan if you're curious I found a solution that involved reversing the order of the image set in the models.

Comment: I posted the same kind of solution in comment then I deleted it because you were confusing me :) Updating an image and adding a new image is two different things.

Comment: @AamirAdnan I saw your solution and tried to use it, but your template code was off and kept returning errors. I couldn't make it work. My solution is based on yours and a suggestion I got on reddit.

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out it is as simple as reversing the order of the image set by adding a Meta class to the Images model.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(...)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pk']
```